# Podspec shows xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint SingleApp.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'SingleApp'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'BingeSDK is a streaming app\'s framework.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
  BingeSDK is a framework for iOS. It makes to provide binge streaming service to other app
                         DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/julianjx1/SingleApp'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Mahir Shahriar Lipeng' => 'mahir.lipeng@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/julianjx1/SingleApp.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'
#  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
#  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
#  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
#  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES' }
#


 
 s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
   'VALID_ARCHS' => 'x86 armv6 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64 '
 }

  s.source_files = 'Source/*.{swift}'
     
     s.resource_bundles = {
       'SingleAppPod' => ['Resource/*.{pdf, storyboard}']
     }
     s.info_plist = {
       'CFBundleIdentifier' => 'org.cocoapods.SingleApp'
     }
     s.swift_versions = ['4', '4.1', '4.2', '5', '5.1']
    # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
     s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
     #s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
     s.dependency 'Alamofire' , '~> 4.9.1'
     #s.dependency 'TextFieldEffects'
  end
```

When I am creating my pod file it shows can't pass to validate my pod. and the failure is
`** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/lipeng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-degcgnjazfnkqzavfjsegbziakno/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire normal (in target 'Alamofire' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

`

After my research I got [cocoapod link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10322). This issue similar like mine but still I can't solve my issue. May be it's an architecture problem. How can I solve this issue